# upgrade from ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04LTS without needing to reinstall and reconfigure i3 windows manager

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, i3-wm

I am thinking that I should upgrade from 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS but am worried that this upgrade will blow away my i3 windows manager configuration and settings. Is there a way to upgrade without potentially causing this problem?

I was thinking it might be possible to upgrade just the kernel without upgrading light-dm and such--which I do not use? But I was not sure if anyone has had any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded and i3 just ran fine without any hassle. For safety I did this: copied my i3 config file to somewhere safe, in case there were issues. But there were none.

Comment: Yep, I just tried upgrading on one of my computers and seems to have worked just fine. There still seem to be some of the normal video driver issues, etc., but hopefully I can find a way to smooth those out.